# Woocommerce - change number of displayed products in loop on archive pages

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I want to change number of displayed products in loop on archive pages. I tried two snippets with no results:

> ```
> // Change the Number of WooCommerce Products Displayed Per Page
> add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', 'lw_loop_shop_per_page', 30 );
>
> function lw_loop_shop_per_page( $products ) {
>  $products = 12;
>  return $products;
> }
> ```
>
> If the above snippet does not work for you, you can use the following
> code snippet.
>
> ```
> // Change the Number of WooCommerce Products Displayed Per Page
> add_filter( 'loop_shop_per_page', create_function( '$products', 'return 12;' ), 30 );
> ```

My goal is to display 50 products per page.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with your own loop like

```
$products = new WP_Query([
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'product',
]);

if($products->have_posts()){
  while ( $products->have_posts() ) {
     $products->the_post();
     wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'product' );
  }
}
```

it will show all products which are published also you can filter them by tax_query, and do pagination

```
$products = new WP_Query([
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'post_per_page' => 0,
    'paged' => get_query_var( 'paged' ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        'relation' => 'AND',
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'pa_size',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => 'small',
        );
        
    ),
]);
```

you can find everything about WP_Query here: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/